# removing on local.xml

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, local.xml

How do I rid of an "addLinkRel" and a "setText" via "local.xml"?
More specific, I'm trying to unload these

```
<action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</href></action>

<block type="core/text" name="head.viewport">
<action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />]]>&#10;</text></action>
</block>
```

Comment: Hey Felope, welcome to @stackMagento. could you please provide more details? At least show us which block holds `addLinkRel` action node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felipe Abranches,You can remove

```
<block type="core/text" name="head.viewport">
<action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />]]>&#10;</text></action>
</block>
```

this above block using remove tag `<remove>` at `local.xml`.

code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <remove name="head.viewport" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

and there nothing default way to remove

```
<action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</href></action>
```

code at local.xml
If you want to remove it then you need go at page and comment that code

Comment: See my answer for how to remove the "addLinkRel". Feel free to update your answer to include that information.

Answer (score 4):

It *is* actually possible to remove the "addLinkRel" without editing page.xml directly.

From the [Magento RWD Guide (see step 2 in the "Removing Sample Data Assets" section)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide#remove-sample-content):

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="removeItem"><type>link_rel</type><name>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</name></action>
</reference>
```